# Page title inside template?

Tags: wordpress, page-title

Is there any way to get my page title via my template, for example a line like this;

```
get page_title()
```

within my template, that would extract the title of that page as defined on each page in the dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following one to get page title :

```
<?php the_title();?>
```

For POST

```
$page_title = $wp_query->post->post_title;

Check for reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Properties.
```

Comment: excellent!!! thankyou i knew itd be something simple like that but im a newbie to wordpress and couldn't find any reference. much appreciated!! :)  - if i wanted to have a side bar with unique content in my template, could i have a page ie: sidebar.php that has an if loop, for example: if $page_title = index { include (sidebar01.php)} else if $page_title= page02 { include (sidebar02)} else { include sidebar03}

Comment: You can create custom sidebar as per your own requirement. http://www.tastyplacement.com/add-sidebar-wordpress